# rewrite subdomain requests to main domain (no redirect)

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to achieve this :

When a use requests a page like :

```
en.domain.com/page.php
en.domain.com/subdir/page.php
```

to rewrite (**not redirect**, just rewrite) to :

```
www.domain.com/page.php
www.domain.com/subdir/page.php
```

However, index.php should be an exception to this rewrite, so if a user requests :

```
en.domain.com/index.php
```

It will read that physical page and not do any rewriting.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(index.php) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^en\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ "http://www.domain.com/$1" [L,P]
```